# Mixing Java swing and JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, netbeans

I am having some troubles with a netbeans platform project where i mix swing and javafx.

I have two tabs, where one tab has a swing button, the other tab contains a javafx TreeTableView. When the button is pressed a new row should be added to the TreeTableView, I have not been able to make this happen though.

Before and after adding a new node, i recursivly print the tree.

```
Root before add: 
Root
-Child 1
-Child 2
Root after add: 
Root
-Child 1
-Child 2
-New child
```

So the underlying datamodel changes, the UI however does not reflect these changes.

Any pointers to what I am missing would be helpful.

[Code download (netbeans project (rar archive))](https://minfil.org/R0Jfted7bf/TreeTableView.rar)

[Code download (netbeans project (zip archive))](https://minfil.org/kdK1tfd6bc/TreeTableView.zip)

Interface to communicate between classes:

```
public interface XAddItem {
    public void add();
}
```

UI topcomponent (Holds treetableview)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.windows.TopComponent;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;
import org.openide.util.lookup.ServiceProvider;

@TopComponent.Description(
        preferredID = "UITopComponent",
        //iconBase="SET/PATH/TO/ICON/HERE", 
        persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS
)
@TopComponent.Registration(mode = "editor", openAtStartup = true)
@ActionID(category = "Window", id = "com.mycompany.ui.UITopComponent")
@ActionReference(path = "Menu/Window" /*, position = 333 */)
@TopComponent.OpenActionRegistration(
        displayName = "#CTL_UIAction",
        preferredID = "UITopComponent"
)
@Messages({
    "CTL_UIAction=UI",
    "CTL_UITopComponent=UI Window",
    "HINT_UITopComponent=This is a UI window"
})
@ServiceProvider(service = XAddItem.class)
public final class UITopComponent extends TopComponent implements XAddItem {

    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");
    final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    TreeTableView ttv = null;

    public UITopComponent() {
        initComponents();
        setName(Bundle.CTL_UITopComponent());
        setToolTipText(Bundle.HINT_UITopComponent());
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        panel.add(jfxPanel);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setup();
            }
        });

        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private void setup() {

        TreeItem<String> child1 = new TreeItem<>("Child 1");
        TreeItem<String> child2 = new TreeItem<>("Child 2");
        root.getChildren().addAll(child1, child2);

        TreeTableColumn<String,String> column = new TreeTableColumn<>("Column");
        column.setPrefWidth(150);   

        //Defining cell content
        column.setCellValueFactory((CellDataFeatures<String, String> p) -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue().getValue()));  

        ttv = new TreeTableView(root);
        ttv.getColumns().add(column);
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(ttv));
    }

    private void printTree(TreeItem<String> i, String level) {
        System.out.println(level + i.getValue());
        for (TreeItem<String> c : i.getChildren()) {
            printTree(c, level + "-");
        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
    }                     

    @Override
    public void add() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Root before add: ");
                printTree(root, "");
                root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("New child"));
                System.out.println("Root after add: ");
                printTree(root, "");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

UI topcomponent (Holds button)

```
package com.mycompany.ui;

import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.util.Lookup;
import org.openide.windows.TopComponent;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;

@TopComponent.Description(
        preferredID = "AddTopComponent",
        //iconBase="SET/PATH/TO/ICON/HERE", 
        persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS
)
@TopComponent.Registration(mode = "editor", openAtStartup = true)
@ActionID(category = "Window", id = "com.mycompany.ui.AddTopComponent")
@ActionReference(path = "Menu/Window" /*, position = 333 */)
@TopComponent.OpenActionRegistration(
        displayName = "#CTL_AddAction",
        preferredID = "AddTopComponent"
)
@Messages({
    "CTL_AddAction=Add",
    "CTL_AddTopComponent=Add Window",
    "HINT_AddTopComponent=This is a Add window"
})
public final class AddTopComponent extends TopComponent {

    XAddItem add = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(XAddItem.class);

    public AddTopComponent() {
        initComponents();
        setName(Bundle.CTL_AddTopComponent());
        setToolTipText(Bundle.HINT_AddTopComponent());
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        org.openide.awt.Mnemonics.setLocalizedText(jButton1, org.openide.util.NbBundle.getMessage(AddTopComponent.class, "AddTopComponent.jButton1.text")); // NOI18N
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        add(jButton1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }                       

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        add.add();
    }                                        

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;                 
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using Swing?  What’s wrong with a JavaFX [Button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html)?

Comment: It is for a bigger project that is biult using swing already, swing however has no built in treetableview